# access denied mysql monitor

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed xampp on 10.9 mavericks. Unfortunately the command mysql does not work in the terminal. I managed to start the mysql monitor from `xamppfiles/bin/`. When I try to create a new database I get

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database XY

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

*No, you should run `mysql -u root -p` in bash, not at the `MySQL command-line`. If you are in mysql, you can exit by typing exit.*

*You may need to set up a root account for your MySQL database:*

*In the terminal type:*

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'root password goes here'
```

*And then to invoke the MySQL client:*

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```